# Error al iniciar la database de MongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

Acabo de instalar MongoDB siguiendo todas las intrucciones del manual. Sin embargo, ya habiendo creado la carpeta de la base de datos, cuando le pongo el siguiente comando:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath="c:\data\db"
```

Me sale un texto enorme en vez de un aviso de que está funcionando o no. Lo he estado intentado leer, pero no veo en ningún lado que hable de una excepción. Os pongo aquí una imagen de parte del resultado en la consola:
[image: Fragmento del resultado de la consola]

¿Alguien sabe qué puede haberme fallado?

Comment: Prueba quitándole el igual al parámetro `--dbpath`. Que te quede algo así, sin el igual: `"C:\...bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath "d:\test\mongo db data"`

Comment: Lo que te muestra es el log de inicialización de la base de datos. Busca en dicho log un mensaje que dice: `"msg": "Waiting for connections", "attr": {"port":27017, ...}`. Esto significa que el servidor está escuchando peticiones. Puedes abrir otro terminal y escribir: `mongo` y verás que te conectas al servidor correctamente. Saludos

Comment: Vale, @MauricioContreras, era eso. Me he confundido por el mensaje que decía la guía de instalación. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como te digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514378/error-al-iniciar-la-database-de-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment914576_514378):

Lo que te muestra es el `log` de inicialización de la base de datos. Busca en dicho log un mensaje que dice:

```
"msg": "Waiting for connections", "attr": {"port":27017, ...}
```

Esto significa que el servidor está escuchando peticiones.

Puedes abrir otro terminal y escribir: `mongo` y verás que te conectas al servidor correctamente.

También puedes verificar que se encuentra instalado como un servicio escribiendo `services.msc` desde el terminal (debes haber iniciado el mismo como administrador), y verificar que se encuentra en inicio automático (busca el servicio que se llama MongoDB).

Por último revisa que tienes la ruta a la carpeta `bin` de tu instalación añadida a la variable PATH del sistema.